Can the wedge product acting on continuous functions be written differently?
I have
$M=\mathbb{R}^2$, $N=\mathbb{R}^3$
$$F(\theta,\phi)=\big((\cos\phi+2)\cos\theta,(\cos\phi+2)\sin\theta,\sin\phi\big)$$
$$\omega=y\text{d}z\wedge\text{d}x$$
Calculating:
$$F^*\omega=F^*(y\text{d}z\wedge\text{d}x)=\big((\cos\phi+2)\sin\theta\text{d}\sin\phi\wedge\text{d}(\cos\phi+2)\cos\theta\big)$$
$$F^*\omega=\big((\cos\phi+2)\cos\phi\sin\theta)\wedge(-\cos\theta\sin\phi-(\cos\phi+2)\sin\theta\big)$$
Can I re-write or simplify the last form into a form without the wedge product (since there are no differentials in it any longer)?
Thanks

No, you’re missing the differentials. Where did $d\phi$ and $d\theta$ disappear to? Keep in mind the final answer is supposed to be a 2-form, i.e in this case, you’re going to need to get some multiple of $d\theta\wedge d\phi$.

@peek-a-boo right!

@peek-a-boo can this be simplified? $$F^\omega=F^(y\text{d}z\wedge\text{d}x)=\big((\cos\phi+2)\sin\theta\text{d}\sin\phi\wedge\text{d}(\cos\phi+2)\cos\theta\big)$$
$$F^*\omega=\big(\cos\phi+2)\cos\phi\sin\theta\text{d}\phi\big)\wedge(-\cos\theta\sin\phi\text{d}\phi-(\cos\phi+2)\sin\theta \text{d}\theta\big)$$

you can distribute the wedges

How? I have tried, can't get anywhere

write things down carefully on a piece of paper and avoid typos. Also, what do you mean how? The distributive law works as we would all hope: $(a+b)\wedge (c+d)=a\wedge c+ a\wedge d+ b\wedge c+b\wedge d$.

Thanks, I see now what you refer to.
